# What is the significance of the zero vector?

Tags: soft-question, vectors, physics, mathematical-physics

When I was studying about vectors and their use in physics, I found something called zero vector. My physics textbook says it is

> A vector whose initial and terminal points coincide is called zero vector, it has zero magnitude but an arbitrary direction, i.e. it cannot be assigned a direction.

My question is What is the significance of this zero vector?

For example, If the force acting on a body has no magnitude then is there any meaning/significance to say that the force has a direction? It can also be said that *a vector +zero vector = same vector*, then what?? Zero vector has bring no change in the vector. I m totally confused regarding the role of this zero vector in mathematics/physics. Please help. 
Thanks

Comment: What is the book's definition for non-zero vectors?

Comment: @dxiv, vectors whose initial and terminal points do not coincide

Comment: OK then, as long as you define a vector as an ordered pair of points, then that definition applies to all vectors. The magnitude can be derived from that definition using whatever metric on the space. The "*direction*" can *only* be defined for non-zero vectors, and it would be more correct to say it's "*undefined*" or "*no direction*" for the zero vector, but that's the sort of math point that physics books often gloss over.

Comment: @dxiv, I mentioned that book says that zero vectors can not be assigned a direction, is it different from what you said??

Comment: `can not be assigned a direction` more closely translates to "*undefined*" which is (slightly) different from `an arbitrary direction` as first stated.

Comment: @dxiv, I shall be thankful if you post an answer with some additional knowledge too, because the answer given does not satisfy me.

Comment: I'll leave it at comments, since I don't think I fully understand the difficulty you are having with the zero vector. If, as you said, vectors are defined as ordered pairs of points, then the zero vector is simply one where the points coincide. I suggest you check out some of the questions listed on the right hand side of this page under `related`, maybe [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2035944/zero-vector-as-a-vector-under-their-definition-by-bellavitis) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1358026/what-makes-a-vector-an-object-with-both-magnitude-and-direction).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps consider that two forces of equal magnitude but opposite direction would have a resultant force of zero magnitude and indeterminate direction. That is, their vector sum would be the zero vector. If there were no zero vector, how else would one describe this situation?

Answer (score 1):

One property of the zero vector is that it is known as the "additive identity". Just like multiplying a number by 1 is the multiplicative identity, multiplying any number by 1 gets the same number back, adding $\vec{0}$ gets the same vector back. That makes it a unique element in any vector space, and it is the one vector every vector space is required to have. In fact, the zero dimensional vector space consists of the set $\left\{\vec{0}\right\}$.

As for thinking about magnitude and direction, that requires a vector space to have another structure that allows you to calculate the length of a vector. That structure is called a metric. The general definition of a vector's direction is the unit vector that points in the same direction as the vector. In notation, a vector's direction is given by:
$$\hat{n} = \frac{\vec{v}}{|\vec{v}|}.$$ For the zero vector, you get $0/0$ for each component, and thus, no definable direction for the zero vector.